# Windows Live Messenger 2011 multiple instances

Tags: windows-live-messenger, multiple-instances

I have been able to open **multiple intances of Windows Live Messenger** with this registry change taken from [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/01/10/enable-multiple-instances-of-windows-live-messenger-for-multi-logins/):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Live\Messenger]
"MultipleInstances"=dword:00000001
```

The problem is that I just installed **version 2011** and it is like that registry key is not taking into account anymore. As opening the program again just brings the other window on top and not another instance.

I have Windows 7 64-bit and installed this new version of MSN by Windows Update.

Does anyone know if this is a new limitation or if there is another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [A-Patch](http://apatch.org/). It works with **Windows Live Messenger 2011** and let you choose some cool customizations like **Polygamy** or removing ads.